# Reducing memory used by make

Tags: cmake

I have been trying to build *xmrig* for the raspberry pi, but it always fails to build because cc1plus ran out of memory. I know the RPi doesn't have a high hashrate, I'm just experimenting. The error that I get when following the official Ubuntu build is:

```
cc1plus: out of memory allocating 5190462000 bytes after a total of 1040547840 bytes
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/xmrig.dir/build.make:2598: CMakeFiles/xmrig.dir/src/crypto/rx/RxDataset.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:118: CMakeFiles/xmrig.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

This is during the *make* command. All the other commands prior worked.

Comment: Are you sure this is cmake consuming that amount of memory. To me this looks like your compiler is the program doing that. Not sure why this tries to allocate >5 GiB of memory. Did you leave out some header guards?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'll try what @ hdf89shfdfs mentioned. I have a 4GB Raspberry Pi 4. I was able to get it to build under Manjaro For ARM 64-bit. Currently, I am using Kali.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my attempt at an answer.

If your system doesn't have enough RAM to support your compiler maybe consider limiting the number of jobs. My coworker has run into this issue when compiling LLVM.

During the build step limit the number of jobs.

```
cmake --build build/ --parallel x
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html

You can limit the number of threads make uses. Cmake definitely isn't using this much memory. The compiler is. You can limit how much memory is being used by limited the amount of threads/jobs the compiler is allowed to use.

Comment: The problem still persists. cc1 plus tries to allocate 5GB of RAM for some reason. Are there any options that I can use to limit the RAM usage of the compiler?